This device has been prevented from starting when the user is not logged in (Code 55)
My computer's network adapter is an Intel Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter. When I am not logged into the computer, the device status for this network adapter shows: 'This device has been prevented from starting when the user is not logged in (Code 55).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My computer has a CT desktop adapter, and I will be prompted :"This device has been prevented from starting when the user is not logged in (Code 55)" I check the properties of this adapter

Is it your own PC, or a corporate asset controlled by IT, who might have added a Group Policy setting to ensure no one else can use it on their network? See https://superuser.com/questions/975912/how-can-i-disable-network-access-for-specific-user for the opposite, where all but one user can use the network.

Please edit the question to provide more information that is asked for.
